# widgets in jquery mobile not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm using backbone, require.js, underscore and jquery mobile for my project. I noticed that some of the widgets from jquery mobile are not loaded mainly header and footer. How can i fix that?

## update

my html

```
<div id="connectionForm">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
    <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
    <a data-icon="check">Save</a>
</div>
<input class="user-input" id="serviceUrl"/>
<a class="save-url btn" data-role="button" data-icon="check">Save</a>
```

on firebug

```
<div class="ui-[object Object]" data-position="inline" data-role="header">
```

on the view to load jquery mobile and stuffs

```
define([
'jquery',
'mobile',
'const',
'underscore',
'backbone',
],function($, Mobile, Const,  _, Backbone){
```

here are the list of widgets it loaded ( using firebug )

```
button
function()

checkboxradio
function()

collapsible
function()

collapsibleset
function()

dialog
function()

listview
function()

navbar
function()

page
function()

selectmenu
function()

slider
function()

textinput
function()

widget
```

Comment: Please include relevant code.  Probably the parts where you load your jqm libraries.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* never-mind, your update shows you are already using the data-role="header"

JQuery Mobile uses the tags

```
<div data-role="header"></div>
```

to define the header section, not the more common usages below

```
<div class="header"></div>
<header></header> (html5)
```

Comment: i dont quite get your answer. i think my problem would be jqm is not loading the header widget. i just dont know how to solve it though but thanks

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part, I thought you may not have been defining the header correctly, rather than the widget not being loaded my jqm.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. by default jqm is not loading header widget or showing it on DOM tab of firebug. So i resulted to updating to 1.1.0 version and everything worked like charm,.